# How do I create a sticky navigation bar in Open Social?

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

I'm using D8 and working on new theme in Open Social witch uses bootstrap/sass. In my theme I want the navigation bar (in the header region) to be sticky at the top of the screen.
I've made some javascript/sass code but I can't get it to work. This is what I have done so far:

Created a new javascript function in the theme_name.js file:

```
    //-- Sticky Header
    (function($) {
        Drupal.behaviors.navbar = {
            attach: function (context, settings) {

                var nbar = $('.header');

                if (nbar.length) {
                    var elmHeight = $('.header-top').outerHeight(true);
                    $(window).scroll(function() {

                        var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
                        if (scrolltop > elmHeight) {
                            if (!nbar.hasClass('sticky')) {
                                nbar.addClass('sticky');
                            }

                        } else {
                            nbar.removeClass('sticky');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    })();
```

This is a code snippet from the navbar.scss file:

```
.navbar-sticky-top {
  @include z-depth-3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: $zindex-navbar-sticky;
}
```

Code snippet from the index.twig file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-sticky-top" id="top"
role="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
...
```

This is the content of the region--header.html.twig file:

```
{% if content %}
  <nav {{ attributes.addClass('navbar navbar-default navbar-sticky-top') }} role="banner">
    <div class="container">
      {{ content }}
    </div>
  </nav>
{% endif %}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're over-complicating it by re-writing things that bootstrap already does.  The stock bootstrap theme and most of it's subthemes should have a setting in the theme for setting a fixed nav bar.

See Appearances -> Theme settings -> Components -> Navbar.  There is an option for fixed top navbar.

If that does not do what you want, there is also the Bootstrap Affix plug-in which should be part of the standard drupal bootstrap theme.

See:  This [W3school page](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the latest version of Open Social, the header bar is sticky. So maybe updating to a newer version helps you out!